# Python 3.9 : BeautifulSoup: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to pull data from a website via a scraper.

```
for findcard in soupurl.find_all('div', class_="v-card"):
    #Declaring global varibles
    global wo_span_name
    global wo_div_phone
    #grab name
    w_span_name = findcard.find('a', class_='business-name')
    wo_span_name = w_span_name.text

    #grab phone number
    w_div_phone = findcard.find('div', class_="phones phone primary")
    wo_div_phone = w_div_phone.text

    #Adding items to list
    phone_list.append(wo_div_phone)
    name_list.append(wo_span_name)
```

When I try this code out I am getting an error

```
wo_span_name = w_span_name.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The weird part is the div, and class exsist, and if I don't try a .text command it will print the Div class

```
"<div class=""phones phone primary"">(Data I am looking for)</div>"
```

I know I am missing something small, but don't know what.

Comment: Your error seems to indicate that there's no div with `class="phones phone primary"` in your document, so `.find()` returns `None`, which doesn't have an attribute called `.text`. You should step through your code and narrow down the cause of the problem. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: See thats the thing I don't get though because it pulls the class="phones phone primary"
if I were comment out `wo_div_phone = w_div_phone.text` and run 'print(w_div_phone)' it will print out all 30 of the numbers `"<div class=""phones phone primary"">(Data I am looking for)</div>"
`

Although I am very new so I might be misunderstanding what you are saying. I think the problem I am having is that it won't div with the data, but won't pull the data and I don't know why.

Comment: On closer inspection, the error is because nothing is returned by `find('a', class_='business-name')`.

Answer (score 0):

So I just kind of cheesed the awnser to this one.

```
w_div_phone = findcard.find('div', class_="phones phone primary")
w1_div_phone = str(w_div_phone)
wo_div_phone = re.sub('\D', '', w1_div_phone)
```

since it was already pulling the div, but would pull the text, I just converted it to a string, and removed all non numeric characters. If someone else has an awnser as to how I could fix it the way it is let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say the `str(w_div_phone)` shows the text in the `div` element, but you are not able to use the `.text()` operator, give the below code a try:

```
w_div_phone = findcard.find('div', class_="phones phone primary")
wo_div_phone_test = w_div_phone.find(text=True)
```